# Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta do not have a function to save every remote server's password

Tags: remote-desktop

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta for manage the remote server.

[image]

But there is an issue for me.

because the Remote Desktop Beta only save the user like this:

[image]

My question is, if I have many remote server, the username all are Administrator, but the password are different.

every time I login a server there I will input password again. because they have a different password.

how to solve this problem?  or is there any tool without this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `domain\username` syntax to distinguish between accounts for different computers – it works with local accounts too, with the computer's short hostname in place of the "domain".

For example, server "WEB-1" uses username `WEB-1\Administrator`;
server "MAIL-2" uses username `MAIL-2\Administrator`; and so on.

Comment: the `WEB-1` I can use random string right?

Comment: No. As I already said, for local accounts that's **the server's hostname.** (The one you see in the server's "System Properties" for example.)